# Is there a closed form for f(n) = n + f(floor(n/2))?

Tags: c, performance, recurrence

I have the following recurrence formula:

```
  f(0) = 0
  f(1) = 1
  f(n) = n + f(floor(n/2))
```

which can be expressed in code as:

```
  int f(int n) {
    int s = 0;
    for (; n; n >>= 1)
      s += n;
    return s;
  }
```

Is there a closed-form that will allow me to compute `f(n)` in one step?

If not, is there anything else I could do to compute `f(n)` more quickly?

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A005187.

Comment: What's wrong with O(log N) complexity?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your usage of these numbers?  You might be able to get away with memoization if your range is fairly contiguous or small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005187) gives this series:

> A005187: a(n) = a([n/2]) + n; also denominators in expansion of
>   1/sqrt(1-x) are 2^a(n); also 2n - number of 1's in binary expansion of
>   2n.

So the second parts gives the formula of `2*n - bitcount(2*n)`. You can calculate this with some efficient bitcount implementation, such as gcc's `__builtin_popcount`.

Answer (score 2):

also note that bitcount(2n) = bitcount(n)

and the derivation is as follows:

let n = sum(b[j] 2^j) for j=0...N

assume b[N] = 1.  define

(a) F(n) = n + F(n/2) = n+n/2+n/4+... = 2 * n - (1/2 + 1/4 + ... 1/2^N) by geometric series

this function F is a real-valued function.  now for each bit b[j] that is set, the floor function subtracts out b[j](sum(1/2^k, k=1...j+1)).  this is because it actually takes out 1/2, but as it propagates the subsequent terms get added.

so

(b) f(n) = floor(F(n)-sum(b[j] sum(1/2^k, k=1...j+1), for j=0...N-1)

substituting (a) into (b) gives

(c)  f(n) = floor(2n - **(1/2 + 1/4 + ... 1/2^(N+1))** - *sum*(b[j] (sum(1/2^(k), for k=1..j+1), for j=0...N-1))

ok, this part is quite cool!  observe that when b[j] is 1, if you sneak 1/2^(j+1) from the bold expression into the italicized sum, the sum inside the sum becomes 1, which means

b[j] (sum(1/2^(k), for k=1..j+1), for j=0...N-1) = sum(b[j], for j=0...N-1)

so equation (c) simplifies to

```
f(n) = floor(2*n - sum(b[j], for j=0...N-1) - remainder)
f(n) = 2*n - bitcount(n-2^N) - 1    ; because remainder >0 and <1
f(n) = 2*n - bitcount(n)            ; b[N]=1, so bitcount(n)=bitcount(n-2^N)+1
```

where remainder is sum(1/2^j, j=1,..N+1 and b[j-1]==0), but this sum is always >0 and < 1 (it is at most 1-1/2^(N+2) and at least 1/2^(N+1), so it can be moved out of the floor as -1.

and also note that bitcount run time can be made equal to the # of bits set (http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/).  some processors have it as a separate instruction.

not sure if latex works here, but it's painful not having math symbols.  i keep having to edit it because something always looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
The function grows as follows - 

f(n) = n + f(n/2)
f(n/2) can be further simplified as - 

n/2 + f(n/4)

If we keep doing this, we will see n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8.....upto log n terms
= n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8...log n terms)
= n[ (1- (1/2)^log n)/(1/2)]
= 2n [1 - (1/2)^log n]

The term (1/2)^log n will become smaller and smaller as n increases, therefore the 2n term dominates. Hence f(n) belongs to big Theta (n)
```

Answer (score 0):

A closed form can arise from http://oeis.org/A005187 as shown below, because:

a(n) = A011371(2n+1)

Since http://oeis.org/A011371:
a(n) = A005187(n) - n, n >= 0

Since http://oeis.org/A005187:
A184835(floor(n/2))

Since http://oeis.org/A184835:
(PARI) {a(n)=local(t=real(polroots(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4-x^5)[1])); n+floor(n/t)+floor(n/t^2)+floor(n/t^3)+floor(n/t^4)}